# MacLaurin Series with 2 variables - error

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a real function $f(x,y)$, where $x,y$ are real.

For a **fixed $x_{0}$** I want to expand $f(x_{0},y)$ in $y_{0}$ in a first order MacLaurin series

How should I write the error with the big O notation?

My try:

$f(x_{0}, y_{0})=f(x_{0}, 0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Bigr|_{\substack{(x,y)=(x_{0}, 0)}} (y_{0} - 0) + O(\Delta y^{2} )$ where $y_{0} - 0= \Delta y$

My doubt is: is correct to write $O(\Delta y^{2} )$ (since $x_{0}$ is fixed) or should I write $O(\Delta y^{2} +\Delta x^{2})$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is totally correct since the function f of multiple variable has become to one of one variable when you fixed the x value. But that Taylor expansion has grade 1, so the O should be y variable power to 1.

If you don't give any value to the x, then the error should be expressed using the length of the (x,y) vector.